# How to set checklistbox repetation as custom?

Tags: asp.net

I have a checklistbox which contains 5 listitems & i have set repetition as vertical now i want to break verticle list after 3 listitems
i.e

listitem1     listitem2   listitem3
listitem4     listitem5

Is is possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you try this

```
checkboxList.RepeatDirection =  RepeatDirection.Horizontal;
checkboxList.RepeatColumns =  3;
```

Answer (score 1):

@StackOverflowException is right.  In addition, you can also set those from markup:

```
<asp:CheckBoxList .. RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatColumns="3" RepeatLayout="Flow" />
```

Flow controls whether a uniform table is used, or a flow layout of elements.

HTH.